# How to completely remove the side dock appearing in activities overview on Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have already disabled the side dock using the Extensions application and the side dock did disappear from the desktop.

[image: normal screen]

However, when I open the applications launcher (using Plank dock) or activities overview, the side dock is still there.

[image: left dock]

How do I make it not appear when I launch the applications launcher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Hide Dash X](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/805/hide-dash/) GNOME Shell extension which does exactly what you want.

Refer to the [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) question if you don't know how to install GNOME Shell extensions.

The reason why the dock was still there, even though you had disabled it, is that it is a different dock. The one you disabled is Ubuntu dock, which is a [Dash to dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/index.html) fork,  while the other is the GNOME Shell dock. When the Ubuntu dock is enabled it replaces the GNOME Shell dock, providing a dock both on the desktop and in the dash (the GNOME Shell dock is shown only in the dash by default). The Hide dash X extension hides the GNOME Shell dock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Comment: i have already even  purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock but it still appears. i am confused.